# Eclipse - class appears in package explorer but can't be found in workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

I have encountered a wierd problem, I have a class that appears in the package explorer inside a certain package but while searching it in the folder of this package I realized it isn't there. I made sure I'm in the correct workspace and all the other classes are there.
Any ideas please?

Comment: Right-click on the file in Eclipse, choose Properties, and look at the Location on the right side. Make sure you're looking at the right place on your hard disk.

Comment: Is this class in a jar or part of a source folder?  If it's in a source folder, the .class file won't be in the output unless the project is built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried refreshing your project / source directory in eclipse? That should do the trick and it if doesn't you've got something really really strange going on